# Unit Test not passing, why?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm a beginner C# student and I have an assignment with the following instructions. I've provided them AS WELL AS my code for the classes I've created just so you can have some context and can see if I've done everything correct

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSdqQ.jpg

I've been trying to create two objects and compare them with the Assert.AreEqual method in my unit test. However, it keeps failing. This is what I've written:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void EmptyAccount()
    {
        //given 
        Person person = new Person("John", "Smith");
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount(person, 0.00);

        //when
        Person person2 = new Person("Michael", "Johnson");
        BankAccount account2 = new BankAccount(person2, 0.00);

        //then
        Assert.AreEqual(account, account2);
    }

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                       
    }
}

public class Person
{       
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName+LastName;
    }
}

public class BankAccount
{      
    public Person Owner
    { get; private set; }

    public static double Balance
    { get; private set; }

    public static double InterestRate
    { get; private set; }

    public BankAccount (Person person, double balance)
    {
        Balance = balance;
        Owner = person; 
    }

    public static void Deposit(double deposit)
    {
        Balance += deposit;
    }

    public static void Withdrawal(double withdrawal)
    {
        Balance -= withdrawal;
    }

    public static void DepositInterest(double interestRate)
    {
        interestRate = InterestRate;
        Balance += (Balance * InterestRate);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Your name is {0} and your balance is {1}", Owner, Balance);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it? I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, but like I said I'm new to programming.

Comment: In order to have a complete question, you should include the relevant code from Person and BankAccount classes. You can review [MCVE] to help determine which parts you should include.

Comment: You need to read up on what a reference type is and what a value type is. `BankAccount` is presumably a reference type and you have two different instances. It's like you and I having the same make, model and year automobile. They are not the same car.

Comment: We need to know more about your BankAccount type. Does it implement IEquatable or IComparable? Otherwise you'll just get reference equality, and those are two very different references.

Comment: @WaliH The relevant information needs to be in the question itself. We don't like viewing code as images, and we especially don't like when essential parts of the questions are hosted on a 3rd party site, where the link could break at any time.

Comment: I've included my code for my classes

Comment: If you want `Assert.AreEqual(account, account2);` to do something other than a reference comparison you need to override `Equals` on `BankAccount`

Comment: Another option is to use a tool that compares the properties of the objects to see if they're equivalent. [FluentAssertions's ShouldBeEquivalentTo](https://medium.com/@pjbgf/asserting-equality-in-your-c-unit-tests-837b423024bf) is an example of this.

Comment: Not meaning to nitpick, but `Person.ToString()` returns `JohnSmith`. Should be `public override string ToString() { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }` and the method `BankAccount.DepositInterest` doesn't require the parameter `interestRate` (maybe your logic is flawed?).

Comment: You can override `Equels` for checking the Equality of Two objects.

Answer (score 2):

Several things are wrong here. The first one is that you are performing a reference comparison (unless `BankAccount` implements `IComparable` or `IEquatable`, which I seriously doubt). Basically, you have two memory addresses to two different objects, and of course they are not equal.

Then, even if you did implement `IComparable`, `IEquatable`, or `IEqualityComparer`, the accounts don't even *look* equal. They are for two different people. With the material presented I would not expect that test to pass.

Comment: Yeah even with the same name it still wouldn't pass

Answer (score 1):

Firts: In your assertion, you are comparing the two BankAccounts via [Referential Equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons), as long as you don't implement [IEquatable< BankAccount >](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and override the Equals(object obj).
So you have basically two options:

1) Test for every comparable property (like int, string, ...) itself and write an assertion for it. 
For example:

```
Assert.AreEqual(account.Owner.FirstName, account2.Owner.FirstName);
Assert.AreEqual(account.Owner.LastName, account2.Owner.LastName);
Assert.AreEqual(account.Balance, account2.Balance);
```

2) Implement the IEquatable - Interface and/or override the Equals(object obj) to make the comparison for equality a job of BankAccount itself.

```
Assert.AreEqual(o1,o2); //basically calls 
o1.Equals(o2);
```

In order to compare them for equality, you will have to at least override the Equals(object obj) method.

```
public class BankAccount
{
  ...
  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    if (!(obj is BankAccount)) return false;
    var other = obj as BankAccount;
    return this.Owner.FirstName == other.Owner.FirstName &&
           this.Owner.LastName  == other.Owner.LastName  &&
           this.Balance         == other.Balance;
  }
}
```

Second: Your test would still fail, since you have different values in there. So for Assert.AreEqual(o1,o2) to succeed, you will have to put the same values in there.

The advantage of the first approach is, that it will show you exactly, where the two accounts are different, while the other just points out, that they are different, using ToString().

In your case, you will have the needed information, due to your override of ToString(), but still, I'd prefer the first one, if you don't need to override the Equals method anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation of @[BradleyDotNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450110/unit-test-not-passing-why/54450145#54450145) was complete about why `AreEqual` return `false` and then your test fail. but I want say what can you do for resolving your problem.

in your case the Owner of `BackAcounts` are different, and it's normal that you get `false` in `AreEqual` method, and your test fail

for writing Unit-test at first step you must decide which unit should tested, and you must define a scenario in your mind.

for example, When the owner of account want withdraw, you must check some condition `(e.g. Account is Empty or not)`

consume that you check these condition in a method with name `CanWithdraw` 
and Then you check if account is empty return `false`.

for testing these scenario you can write this test:

```
...
[TestMethod]
public void CanWithdraw_AccountIsEmpty_ReturnsFalse()
{
    var person = new Person("John", "Smith");
    var account = new BankAccount(person, 0.00);
    var result = account.CanWithdraw();

    Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

I hope this answer help you.